# Jenkins Frequent Disconnects - ClosedChannelException

Tags: jenkins

For the last month or so, two of our windows slaves (connected via JNLP) have started to frequently disconnect. I am pretty sure that something changed in terms of our network, since this only affects one geographical location (and all the slaves in that location) and there was a distinct time when we started receiving the node offline emails, but so far our infrastructure team has drawn a blank.

The error I am seeing in the slave logs is:

```
JNLP agent connected from xx
Slave.jar version: 3.4.1
This is a Windows agent
Agent successfully connected and online
ERROR: Connection terminated
[8mha:////4EVWKVufSpoBsjG/AK97kvCQst6o1LLM9fjogkB0XVcIAAAAWB+LCAAAAAAAAP9b85aBtbiIQSmjNKU4P08vOT+vOD8nVc8DzHWtSE4tKMnMz/PLL0ldFVf2c+b/lb5MDAwVRQxSaBqcITRIIQMEMIIUFgAAckCEiWAAAAA=[0mjava.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.NetworkLayer.onRecvClosed(NetworkLayer.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.impl.NIONetworkLayer.ready(NIONetworkLayer.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.remoting.protocol.IOHub$OnReady.run(IOHub.java:721)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I have spent hours trying to figure out what is wrong. I am not sure what logger I can configure to try and diagnose this further, so if anyone can help me there it would be appreciated? Or indeed any other way of diagnosing what has gone awry.

We are running the latest LTS release 2.46.1 (but it was exhibiting this problem on an older LTS release, and I upgraded to see if the recent remoting changes helped, which unfortunately they didn't.)

I suspect the problem may be on the master side, since I can connect to another master from the same slave machine and don't see the disconnects.

Any help would be appreciated since I am all out of ideas.

thanks, Stu

Comment: Did you ever find the problem? I'm experiencing the same on the latest LTS.

Comment: @stuartjsmith Experiencing the same issue. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with AWS ECS slave agents, for some of failing builds advise in [this article](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remoting+issue) helped.
Try to add `-Dhudson.remoting.Launcher.pingIntervalSec=-1` to slave JVM options and execute following in the master console

`Jenkins.instance.injector.getInstance(hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.class).@pingIntervalSeconds = -1
Jenkins.instance.injector.getInstance(hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger.class).@pingTimeoutSeconds = -1`

Comment: I don't think it's a Ping issue based on this https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Remoting+issue

Answer (score 0):

It might be a certificate error.
Open up the jenkins-slave.xml file, add the argument `-noCertificateCheck`

```
<arguments>-Xrs -jar "%BASE%\slave.jar" -jnlpUrl <master jenkins server url/slave-agent.jnlp -secret <secret> -noCertificateCheck</arguments>
```

Restart the service, and check if the problem persists.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this, although I would have thought that if there were certificate problems then it would not connect at all, not connect for a bit then drop off.

Comment: No, unfortunately no joy. I have the infrastructure guys looking into it again :/

Comment: @stuartjsmith have you found the cause? I met a similar issue now also using 2 windows slaves. It disconnects pretty much around the same time everyday though it can also happen other times.

Comment: Hi, no still not resolved. I have taken some dumps from wireshark and can see tcp rentransmissions being sent from the master to the agent, and then a tcp reset when there is no response. So it looks like the reset is happening on the master side because the client is not acknowledging, but it's still with our infra team to tell me why!